# Check Sent mails are CC if not CC Automatically in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, office-2016, outlook-2016

I want to copy all mails sent from `op1@example.com` to be copied to `manager@example.com`.

I know I can do this applying a rule in outlook. But I want to the rule to check if `op1@example.com` have already put `manager@example.com` in CC field when sending the mail and if not I want to automatically CC it to  `manager@example.com`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through MAilItem.Recipients collection and check the Recipient.Address property.